# Combobox binding breaks when dropped down

Tags: c#, silverlight, data-binding

I have a `ComboBox` which is bound to a `DependencyProperty`  on my form. I can add items to this property through a `Button` click and it will add them to the `ComboBox`. However, as soon as I drop down the `ComboBox` the binding breaks. I can still add items to the property, but my `ComboBox` never updates to show them.

For example

- Click the `Button` three times
- Drop the `ComboBox` down - It will have three items
- Click the `Button` another three times
- Drop the `ComboBox` down - It will still only have three items

Starting the application again and:

- Click the `Button` six times
- Drop the `ComboBox` down - It will have six items

### XAML

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot"
      Background="White">
    <ComboBox Name="combTest"
              ItemsSource="{Binding Users}"
              Width="50"
              Height="50"
              HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
    <Button Click="ButtonBase_OnClick"
            Width="50"
            Height="50"
            HorizontalAlignment="Right" />
</Grid>
```

### Code Behind

```
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.DataContext = this;
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty UsersProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
 "Users", typeof (List<string>), typeof (MainPage), new PropertyMetadata(new List<string>()));

public List<string> Users
{
    get { return (List<string>) GetValue(UsersProperty); }
    set { SetValue(UsersProperty, value); }
}

private int i = 0;

private void ButtonBase_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   Users.Add("User " + i++);
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use **ObservableCollection** instead of **List**

**ObservableCollection** would raise property change of adding and removing item in the collection, but **List** not.

Comment: To add to this answer, having a `List` as a DependencyProperty will only raise changes to the List itself, not its content. So if you do `Users = new List<string>()`, it will be updated, but not if you simply use one of its method, like `Add`.